# HTML Shape not showing up correctly on the web browser, but link works

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an animated colored shape with an link in it that is not showing up in the web browser correctly. When I run it on w3schools.com or on the web page designer, it looks perfect.  However, when it actually gets pushed out, it shows the link but not he shape, animation, or the color.  Here is my code I am using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.button {
border-radius: 500px;
background-color: #00c2a2;
border: none;
color: #0f1211;
text-align: center;
font-size: 25px;
padding: 2px;
width: 250px;
transition: all 0.5s;
cursor: pointer;
margin: px;
}
.button span {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.button span:after {
content: '\00bb';
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
top: 0;
right: -30px;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.button:hover span {
padding-right: 30px;
}
.button:hover span:after {
opacity: 1;
right: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2></h2>
<button class="button"><span><script src="https://js.churchcenter.com/modal/v1"></script>
<a href="https://tlcworshipcenter.churchcenter.com/giving" data-open-in-church-center-modal="true">Partner With Us!</a> </span></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may have to clear your cache before the changes you've made will get recognized.  When you mention it works for w3schools/etc what does it look like? What does it look like for real?  Might help folks answer and improve your questions acceptance rate.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.button {
border-radius: 500px;
background-color: #00c2a2;
border: none;
color: #0f1211;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;

padding: 10px;
width: 250px;
transition: all 0.5s;
cursor: pointer;

}
.button span {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
transition: 0.5s;



}
.button span:after {
content: '\00bb';

position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
top: 0;
right: -30px;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.button:hover span {
padding-right: 25px;

}
.button:hover span:after {
opacity: 1;
right: 0;
}

.button span a{

text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 700;

}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2></h2>
<button class="button"><span><script src="https://js.churchcenter.com/modal/v1"></script>
<a class="text" href="https://tlcworshipcenter.churchcenter.com/giving" data-open-in-church-center-modal="true">Partner With Us!</a> </span></button>
</body>
</html>
```